# setter getter php Перебрать все атрибуты экземпляра объекта

Tags: getter, php, setter

Пример:

```
class XXXDictionary{

private $attributes;
/**
 * Setter
 * 
 * @param string $name
 * @param variant $value
 * @return void
 */
private function __set($name,$value){
$this->attributes[$name]=$value;
}

/**
 * Getter
 * 
 * @param String $name
 * @return variant or FALSE
 */
private function __get($name){
    if(!isset($this->attributes[$name]))
        return false;
    return $this->attributes[$name];
}
}
```

Код получения объекта:

```
 $obj=new XXXDictionary();$obj->propertyName='propertyValue';
```

Как получить список всех свойств, например в цикле!?

Хочется, чтобы работала следующая конструкция:

```
foreach($obj as $propertyName=>$propertyValue) echo $propertyName;
```

Что необходимо добавить в описание класса для доступности данной фичи?

Постараюсь сразу ответить на вопрос "зачем?": Я пишу парсер pdf файлов и у меня создается объект словарь (коллекция). Каждый словарь содержит N атрибутов. Все атрибуты я храню во внутреннем приватном массиве (плюс доп. инфу для парсинга). Итак, класс я представил урезанным, но как видно сеттеры и геттеры позволяют обращаться к свойствам. Если кто то воспользуется моим классом для парсинга pdf, то он сможет обращаться напрямую к объектам -  по цепочке. Дойдя до словаря я бы хотел дать пользователю возможность просмотра всех атрибутов через прогон в цикле.

Метод, отдающий массив имен атрибутов не предлагать, если только этот метод не подхватывается foreach.

Answer (score 1):

foreach может перебирать только public свойства, к private и protected доступ закрыт, но ты можешь написать public функцию внутри класса которая будет выдавать тебе этот список, только перебирать нужно не сам объект, а массив в который складируеш все эти свойства, например:

```
public function show(){
    foreach($this->attributes as $propertyName=>$propertyValue)
        echo $propertyName;
}
```

и обращаться к ней

```
$obj = new XXXDictionary();
$obj -> propertyName = 'propertyValue';
$obj -> show();
```

Comment: Это не дело. Так кул. прогеры не поступают)) Шутка. Я уже нашел решение: нужно наследовать как минимум от ArrayObject, что я и сделал. Теперь foreach прогоняет мои проперти. перегрузка метода offsetSet закрывает на запись все атрибуты, ну а геттер, как вспомогательный инструмент для обращения к свойствам. Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.